Create rows which include values from previous and next rows
I have a longitudinal dataframe consisting of multiple IDs and multiple observations (OBS) per ID. Depending on the number of occasions (OCC) the observations are flagged with each new dose (ADMIN):
ID TIME ADMIN OBS OCC 
1  0    10    0    1
1  1    0     1000 1
1  8    0     560  1
1  12   0     203  1
1  24   10    56   2
1  32   0     674  2
1  36   0     457  2
2  0    20    0    1
2  12   0     144  1
2  24   20    32   2
2  36   0     97   2
2  48   20    199  3
2  60   0     120  3 

I would like to create rows for each ID between two occasions. This new row should have the OCC number from the previous row and the TIME from the next row. Other column values can be set to zero. It should look like this:
ID TIME ADMIN OBS OCC 
1  0    10    0    1
1  1    0     1000 1
1  8    0     560  1
1  12   0     203  1
1  24   0     0    1
1  24   10    56   2
1  32   0     674  2
1  36   0     457  2
2  0    20    0    1
2  12   0     144  1
2  24   0     0    1
2  24   20    32   2
2  36   0     97   2
2  48   0     0    2
2  48   20    199  3
2  60   0     120  3 

A dplyr solution would be highly appreciated. I have tried grouping by ID, filtering by occasions and using slice(n) or slice(1) to obtain last and first rows, respectively but I am a bit stuck now.

One way to achieve this is through reframe() (transform each group to an arbitrary number of rows, e.g. add an extra row)  -- we can group by ID & OCC and add a row to each group by appending extra item to each column vector. NA used for TIME serves as flag and placeholder for the next step where we replace NAs with leading TIME values; no need to touch grouping variables.
slice_head(n = -1, by = ID) drops last row from each group, here it removes rows that were added to the end of each ID block, i.e we only keep additions that were placed between two occasions within each ID group.
library(dplyr)

df |> 
  reframe(
    TIME  = c(TIME, NA),
    ADMIN = c(ADMIN, 0),
    OBS   = c(OBS,   0),
    .by = c(ID, OCC)
  ) |> 
  mutate(
    new  = if_else(is.na(TIME), '*', ''),
    TIME = if_else(is.na(TIME), lead(TIME), TIME)
  ) |> 
  slice_head(n = -1, by = ID)
#>    ID OCC TIME ADMIN  OBS new
#> 1   1   1    0    10    0    
#> 2   1   1    1     0 1000    
#> 3   1   1    8     0  560    
#> 4   1   1   12     0  203    
#> 5   1   1   24     0    0   *
#> 6   1   2   24    10   56    
#> 7   1   2   32     0  674    
#> 8   1   2   36     0  457    
#> 9   2   1    0    20    0    
#> 10  2   1   12     0  144    
#> 11  2   1   24     0    0   *
#> 12  2   2   24    20   32    
#> 13  2   2   36     0   97    
#> 14  2   2   48     0    0   *
#> 15  2   3   48    20  199    
#> 16  2   3   60     0  120

Example data:
df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = 
"ID TIME ADMIN OBS OCC 
1  0    10    0    1
1  1    0     1000 1
1  8    0     560  1
1  12   0     203  1
1  24   10    56   2
1  32   0     674  2
1  36   0     457  2
2  0    20    0    1
2  12   0     144  1
2  24   20    32   2
2  36   0     97   2
2  48   20    199  3
2  60   0     120  3")


One way is to filter the rows where OCC increases by 1, modify the columns as required, then add that to the original data, and sort.
library(dplyr)

bind_rows(df,
          filter(df, OCC-lag(OCC, default=1)==1, .by=ID) |>
            mutate(ADMIN=0, OBS=0, OCC=OCC-1)) |>
  arrange(ID, TIME, ADMIN) 
___
# A tibble: 16 × 5
      ID  TIME ADMIN   OBS   OCC
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1     0    10     0     1
 2     1     1     0  1000     1
 3     1     8     0   560     1
 4     1    12     0   203     1
 5     1    24     0     0     1
 6     1    24    10    56     2
 7     1    32     0   674     2
 8     1    36     0   457     2
 9     2     0    20     0     1
10     2    12     0   144     1
11     2    24     0     0     1
12     2    24    20    32     2
13     2    36     0    97     2
14     2    48     0     0     2
15     2    48    20   199     3
16     2    60     0   120     3


df <- structure(list(ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), 
    TIME = c(0, 1, 8, 12, 24, 32, 36, 0, 12, 24, 36, 48, 60), 
    ADMIN = c(10, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 20, 0, 20, 0, 20, 0), OBS = c(0, 
    1000, 560, 203, 56, 674, 457, 0, 144, 32, 97, 199, 120), 
    OCC = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -13L))

